# Why amp-list is showing previous result when it's src changes and new src response is null or empty?

Tags: amp-html, google-amp

I am working on amp-website.

I have one page with list of items. And for each item there is one link(or button) which will *show similar items*. For showing similar items I am using amp-list.

Now problem is suppose I click on *similar item link for one item* and it will show me the similar items, and after that I came back to listing page from similar items popup and click on some others items similar item link and for that item if *similar items is not present* then similar item popup shows previous item's similar items.(*Amp-list is not changing list*)

How can I resolve this things. Means if similar items is **not available** I want to show "**No similar items found**" message and if similar **items available** then want to **show that items**.

Answer (score 0):

When you use AMP State be aware that it merges received data but doesn't rewrite, so it may be a reason of your issue. When you get null it just put it in the state as a new value but all old values still available. To override your old result you need to set null for all old values